# VS code not showing .git file in version control which is added in subfolder of project

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, .git-folder

I added .git folder in subfolder(not in root folder) in one of my project.
but it is not showing in version control of vs code.

I tried added in .git in main folder then it is adding all files for staging which I don't want because it is not related to my project.

Although I can create new folder for my project but I have to solve this.

Expected: version control should display .git folder added in subfolder.

Comment: I don't think git will allow you to add a directory called `.git`, even if it is inside a subdirectory (it is not uncommon to have nested repos for different reasons).

Comment: @eftshift0 not sure about when the sub .git is not in "parent" git system's .gitignore, but I've used this in a project where a sub .git was in the "parent" system's .gitignore- specifically for easing deployment of a final-build-output folder to github-pages.